# Is there a way to generate 100K unique 8-9 characters in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the below macro to generate 100K unique IDS/Strings in excel.

However, it's failing to generate more than 34,464 rows. I get "#NA"

I am not an expert so there's something definitely wrong.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Sub Random_Number()

Const strCharacters As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

```
Dim cllAlphaNums As Collection
Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 100000) As String
Dim varElement As Variant
Dim strAlphaNum As String
Dim AlphaNumIndex As Long
Dim lUbound As Long
Dim lNumChars As Long
Dim i As Long

Set cllAlphaNums = New Collection
lUbound = UBound(arrUnqAlphaNums)
lNumChars = Len(strCharacters)

On Error Resume Next
Do
    strAlphaNum = vbNullString
    For i = 1 To 9
        strAlphaNum = strAlphaNum & Mid(strCharacters, Int(Rnd() * lNumChars) + 1, 1)
    Next i
    cllAlphaNums.Add strAlphaNum, strAlphaNum
Loop While cllAlphaNums.Count < lUbound
On Error GoTo 0

For Each varElement In cllAlphaNums
    AlphaNumIndex = AlphaNumIndex + 1
    arrUnqAlphaNums(AlphaNumIndex) = varElement
Next varElement

Range("A1").Resize(lUbound).Value = Application.Transpose(arrUnqAlphaNums)

Set cllAlphaNums = Nothing
Erase arrUnqAlphaNums
```

End Sub

Comment: If you just want 100k unique IDs, can't you just assign them to an incrementing counter?

Comment: You have reached the limits of application.transpose

Comment: Chances are slim but you might run into a problem where your strAlphaNum is already in your collection.

Comment: Thank you all. Greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go 2-dimensional from the start and don't use `TRANSPOSE()`:

```
Sub Random_Number()

    Const strCharacters As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    Dim cllAlphaNums As Collection
    Dim arrUnqAlphaNums(1 To 100000, 1 To 1) As String '  column-compatible
    Dim varElement As Variant
    Dim strAlphaNum As String
    Dim AlphaNumIndex As Long
    Dim lUbound As Long
    Dim lNumChars As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set cllAlphaNums = New Collection
    lUbound = UBound(arrUnqAlphaNums, 1)
    lNumChars = Len(strCharacters)

    On Error Resume Next
    Do
        strAlphaNum = vbNullString
        For i = 1 To 9
            strAlphaNum = strAlphaNum & Mid(strCharacters, Int(Rnd() * lNumChars) + 1, 1)
        Next i
        cllAlphaNums.Add strAlphaNum, strAlphaNum
    Loop While cllAlphaNums.Count < lUbound
    On Error GoTo 0

    For Each varElement In cllAlphaNums
        AlphaNumIndex = AlphaNumIndex + 1
        arrUnqAlphaNums(AlphaNumIndex, 1) = varElement
    Next varElement

    Range("A1").Resize(lUbound).Value = arrUnqAlphaNums

    Set cllAlphaNums = Nothing
    Erase arrUnqAlphaNums
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

`arrUnqAlphaNums` has been `Dim'ed` to be column-compatible from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're a life saver :)